# Python: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file on csv file

Tags: python, valueerror

When I run the following code:

```
def read_s_par_csv(file_name):

    with open(file_name,'r') as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)

        vg = []
        vd = []

        for row in csvReader:
            vg.append(row[0])
            vd.append(row[1])

    return vg,vd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vg,vd = read_s_par_csv('./s_par_test.csv')
    print(vg)
```

I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "..", line 201, in  vg,vd = read_s_par_csv('./s_par_test.csv')
>   File "..", line 189, in read_s_par_csv for row in csvReader: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: This error could happen if the block with the for loop is not inside the `with open(...)` block.  How is it in your code ?

Comment: the for loop is exactly the way I have written here, inside the with open(...) in my code.

Comment: The line numbers make me think there's more to this code. If you run _just this example_, does it produce the same error?

Comment: the rest of the code is irrelevant to this part. Even if I make a new file and run it, it shows the same problem.

Comment: error indicate the file was closed while it was read, but your code doesn't have this problem

Comment: Yes, i don't understand why